# How to get pointer to internal data-array inside python library into python using ctypes interface

Tags: python, pointers, interface, fortran, ctypes

I have large Fotran library (for quantum chemistry) which internally stores variable `bbnkre` which is 3D array containing coefficients of wavefunction.
I want to get access to this internal array (both read and write/modify) from python **without copying the content** of that array.

Main reason why I want to avoid copying is to save memory and time required for copying the whole array, when I want to modify just part of it.

Currently I have following, but it does not seem to work:

**In Fortran:**

```
! somewhere in module
real, dimension (:, :, :), allocatable, target :: bbnkre

...

!interface subroutine exposed to library interface
subroutine firecore_getPointer_wfcoef( bbnkre_ ) bind(c, name='firecore_getPointer_wfcoef')
    use iso_c_binding
    use density
    implicit none
    type(C_PTR),      intent(out) :: bbnkre_
    bbnkre_ = c_loc( bbnkre ) 
end subroutine
```

**In Python**

```
array3d  = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.double, ndim=3, flags='CONTIGUOUS')
lib.firecore_getPointer_wfcoef.argtypes  = [array3d] 
lib.firecore_getPointer_wfcoef.restype   =  None
def firecore_getPointer_wfcoef(bbnkre):
    return lib.firecore_getPointer_wfcoef(bbnkre)
```

Comment: You have `dtype=np.double`: are you expecting this to match a Fortran real variable?

Comment: What does "it does not seem to work" mean?  Show expected vs. actual output and update with tested code that reproduces the issue.  You probably at least need `flags='F_CONTIGUOUS'`  since the array is passed to Fortran.